# Making a Dreamservice selectable as a custom Ambient Mode screensaver

Tags: android, android-tv, google-tv, dreamservice

I have an app with a custom Dreamservice activity that can be selected as a screensaver on most Android TV and Google TV set-top box devices, and some Android TV smart TVs. With some of the latest model Google TV smart TVs, this appears to have been replaced with "Ambient Mode"

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/dreams/DreamService

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/ambient-mode

In the settings for ambient mode on the TVs, there appears to be a selection for experimental/3rd party sources, but there is no documentation on which activity filter to apply to cause the Dreamservice activity to be made selectable here, and it does not appear with the old manifest attributes. Are Dreamservices no longer supported by Google TV? How can I make my Dreamservice selectable in this menu?

Comment: this has been answered here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/73460290/247257